# Issue with responsive menu (XML and ASP Menu)

Tags: css, asp.net, xml

I am using XML menu with ASP.Net to display the menu, and styling them with the custom CSS, The issue is with the menus on Mobile devices.
Consider the below screenshot,
[image]

CSS Code,

```
.menuxml{
display:none;
background-color: #006969;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 95%;
font-weight: 500;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 20px;
}
.main_menu,
.main_menu:visited,
.main_menu:hover {
text-align: center;
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
margin-right: 8px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
}

.main_menu:hover {
background-color: #004949;
color: #ffffff;
}

.level_menu,
.level_menu:visited,
.level_menu:hover {
min-width: 100px;
border-bottom:1px solid #ccc!important;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
color: #000000;
text-align: left;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
padding-left: 7px;
padding-right: 5px;
}

.level_menu:hover {
background-color: #004949;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

I have tried `word-wrap`, `word-break` and `display:inline`
Live test can be done with `https://www.includehelp.com/`

Answer (score 0):

Since you used  'white-space: no-wrap' for dropdown options, Add new class to specific dropdown and add css(left: -120px).[refer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crW4z.png)

Comment: This may possible but tough to manager because most of the CSS classes related these menus are not designed by me - they are automatic. Is there any way to break the line if it exceeds the width.

Comment: => update the tags, class, ids given below,
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  #ctl00_header_cntrl1_Menu1 ul.dynamic {
    z-index: 1;
    right: 0;
  }


  #ctl00_header_cntrl1_Menu1 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }

  .level_menu, .level_menu:visited, .level_menu:hover {
    min-width: 120px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc!important;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 2% 10% 2% 10%;
  }